# How should i display a 'non checked' checkbox?

Tags: checkboxes, user-feedback

At the moment i'm making a redesign for a page where the customer can fill in their preferences for receiving a newsletter.

There are four options that can be selected and on the enterance of the page they are all 'checked'.

If the visitor deselect an option, than there will appear a red cross is the checkbox

[image: image 1= checked]
[image: image 2= not checked]

Is it a good idea to keep these form of deselection feedback in the new design, or should i let the box empty if it is not selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An deselected checkbox is an empty checkbox. Leaving the red cross may indicate that the check box remains selected.

more info at: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700393.aspx

[image]

Comment: In addition, low-vision people might have a hard time distinguishing between the checkmark and cross.